# How to cancel console.log messages in ionic release/production apk

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic, and in the publishing phase I am following the instructions here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html

The release apk is generated, but it's still outputting the console.log messages when I view the app's logcat.

I do not have the "cordova-plugin-console plugin" installed (never had).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This maybe not a right answer about your question, but I'll provide an alternative solution for debugging with console. Because I don't know why your app could print out messages from the `console.log` without that plugin.

If you had never installed the `cordova-plugin-console` plugin before, the best ways is write down your own `Logging` factory/class/function with a `switcher` flag. This should be the wrapper of the `console.log`.

During the debugging, call your logging function.
In your logging function, check if `switcher` flag is enabled, then invoke the `console.log`, else do nothing.

#### Here is an example:

```
yourApp.factory('Debug', [function(){
    var IS_DEBUGGING = true; //change this to false whenever you want to release your app.
    return function(msg){
        if (IS_DEBUGGING) {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    }
}]);
```

I suggest do this as a factory, you could customize and extend this for the logging level of your app.